# Having trouble writing to a file

Tags: java, ioexception, filewriter

I have a Gui for a stopwatch, it has a Start button, a Stop button, and also a "Split" button, and a Save Splits button. The stopwatch records splits and I would like to be able to write them to a file but I have an error with:

```
FileWriter splitsWriter= new FileWriter("a.txt");
for(int i=0;i<theSplits.size();i++){
    splitsWriter.write(theSplits.get(i));
}
```

It says `Unhandled exception type IOException` but I thought a writer creates the file if it doesn't exist so why should this exception be a problem? I'm just confused..

Comment: You should add a catch block and get the details of the IOException. Maybe it is "Access Denied" or another such error.

Comment: Hmm I just don't understand why it's a compiler error, I haven't used FileReader/FileWriter much before but I used it about a week ago on something and didn't have this issue.

Comment: You are getting the compile error if you do not have a catch block. I thought you were getting an unhandled IOException being thrown by the program. You can't compile until you have a catch handler. See Alex's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like pstrjds already said you have to add a try/catch block. Your code should look like this:

```
try {
    FileWriter splitsWriter= new FileWriter("a.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<theSplits.size();i++){
        splitsWriter.write(theSplits.get(i));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Do something to handle the exception
}
```

This should compile.

Comment: Compiles and runs with no errors, creates the text file but doesn't actually write to it but I think I can figure that out.

EDIT: woops forgot to close the writer, works fine now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't forget to close the stream. So after your for(...) {} you should put splitsWriter.close();